# SqlCommand with parameters accepting different data formats

Tags: c#, sql-server

Imagine this code:

```
string value = "1.23";
string query = "UPDATE MYTABLE SET COL1=@p1";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", value);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

On my database it will work with value="1.23" if COL1 is decimal type column. But it will fail if value is "1,23" (comma instead of a dot as a decimal point). The error is

> Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric

I'd like it to work in both cases with  "value" being a string variable.

Unfortunately I cannot just replace comma for the dot as this code is going to be more universal, dealing both with `numeric` and `varchar` columns

Is there any way that an query accepts a parameter with number written as a string both with dot and a comma and correctly puts it in into table?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Try parsing it into a Double type either way, then put the double into your parameter (BTW, it's good form to let the sql command know what type the parameter is expected to be)

Comment: Use Double.TryParse or Decimal.TryParse.

Comment: Would it be an option to always store with the dot, and, after retrieving, change to comma depending on the `CurrentUICulture`?

Comment: Does it not depend on where the `value` is coming from. The comma versus dot decimal marker is culture dependent and is part of the displayed value, not the stored value for a number. If it's from the interface then it needs to be culture aware.

Comment: In that case I will advise you to make COL1 in your database a nvarchar data type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the value isn't semantically a string, you shouldn't send it as a `string`. The type of the parameter value is important, and influences how it is transmitted *and* can lead to culture issues (comma vs dot, etc).

If the value is semantically a decimal, then use something like:

```cs
string value = "1.23";
var typedValue = decimal.Parse(value); // possible specifying a culture-info
//...
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", typedValue);
```

Then it should work reliably.

---

Unrelated, but you can make ADO.NET a lot easier with tools like "Dapper":

```cs
connection.Execute("UPDATE MYTABLE SET COL1=@typedValue", new { typedValue });
```

Comment: What are your thoughts on `AddWithValue`?  I see a lot of comments lately saying the type inference can be problematic.

Comment: @ParrishHusband [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: @LarsTech yeah Joel's article is a good read.  I was hoping Marc might weigh in if he agrees or disagrees.  Not sure anything has changed since 2014.

Comment: @Parrish Husband IMO AddWithValue() is fine if your using stored procedures (which are typed).

Comment: @ParrishHusband the reason that I don't have strong opinions on `AddWithValue` is that I *almost always* uses Dapper over raw ADO.NET; I'd much sooner say "stop using raw ADO.NET" than "stop using AddWithValue". The while AddWithValue debate is just the tip of the iceberg in terms of common causes of problems in ADO.NET that are easily side-stepped by using any of the available tools

Comment: Thanks. I hoped there is some setting which means "accept numbers written in any culture as sql command parameters". But it seems it won't be that easy. So I'll go the suggested way. Before adding my parameter I'll try checking if it is a number with different culture settings and if it is indeed a number I'll be adding it as number, not as a string to the query.

Comment: @RRM "I'll try checking if it is a number with different culture settings" - I cannot express sufficiently quite how bad an idea that is. The number "123,456" is valid under multiple cultures, but in some it means 123-thousand, and in others it means 123-and-a-bit. Likewise, "123.456". Equally, the date "2019/06/07" is valid in multiple cultures, but in some it is in June, and in others it is in July. DO NOT SCAN CULTURES. There are exactly two options; a) you know what culture you expect, or b) your data is corrupt